# I can only receive mail sent by the PHP mail function from e-mail addresses on the same domain

Tags: php, email

I am using the PHP mail() function to send e-mail. I am able to receive mail sent from my web app at an e-mail from the same domain (e.g. if my web app is on mywebsite.com, I can only receive emails from the app from the address me@mywebsite.com). I have tried to send mail to two Gmail addresses and an Outlook address and it is not getting received.

Here's my mail function:

```
mail($email, "Subject", $message, "From: somebody@mywebsite.com\r\nContent-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1");
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: If it's going to spam you should look into additional header options, like setting the envelope address if it doesn't automatically match what you're defining in your above code.

Answer (score 0):

That could be a spam problem.
You are probably using sendmail to send the actual email from the server. You need to take a look at the logs of the MTA (postfix?) In order to have more details.

Answer (score 0):

Check your server's SMTP setting. 
Also it may go to SPAM folders of gmail or outlook, please check.